# Proc SQL with space in the column name

Tags: sql, sas, 4gl

How I can use column with space in the name ('library name') in `PROC SQL` in SAS?

```
proc sql outobs=10;
    select *
    from sashelp.vtable 
    where library name = xxx
    ;
run;
```

I tried:

```
proc sql outobs=10;
    select *
    from sashelp.vtable 
    where 'Libname'n = test_lin;
quit;

proc sql outobs=10;
    select *
    from sashelp.vtable 
    where 'library name'n = test_lin;
quit;

proc sql outobs=10;
    select *
    from sashelp.vtable 
    where libname = test_lin;
quit;
```

> ERROR: The following columns were not found in the contributing
>   tables: test_lin.

[sashelp.vtable](http://postimg.org/image/ajthgw6g1)

Variable Name: `libname`

Variable Label: `Library Name`

Comment: Try `where libname = test_lin`: you do not need SAS Name Literals for `libname`. `'Libname'n` makes it case-sensitive.

Comment: Looks like `test_lin` is a variable. You put it here like just another column name.

Comment: Yes, where libname = 'TEST_LIN' works!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [documentation - SAS Name Literals](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000998953.htm):

```
proc sql outobs=10;
    select *
    from sashelp.vtable 
    where 'library name'n = xxx
    ;
run;
```

> A **SAS name literal** is a name token that is expressed as a string
>   within quotation marks, followed by the upper- or lowercase letter **n**.
>   ... You can use a name literal only for variables, statement labels, and **DBMS column and table names**.

Comment: I get - ERROR: The following columns were not found in the contributing tables: BF_REF, library name.

Comment: Well, do you have those columns in `sashelp.vtable`? The error itself indicates that SAS is looking for the column `library name` now.

Comment: @PNPTestovir: just checked sashelp.vtable in my environment (sas9.3, sas base), got only 
`libname` as column name but not `library name`, are you sure the column exists in you environment? If yes then maybe this could be another question...

Comment: Please try it observing the case: `'Library Name'n`.

Comment: The same for 'Library Name'n.

Comment: @pnptestovir: I guess library name is only label name, not variable name, try libname instead. Or do a proc contents on vtable to verify.EDIT: Checked it with proc contents, library name is only label, to access it you must use variable name which is libname

Comment: Try `describe view sashelp.vtable` to see the actual column names. 'Library Name' can be a display alias for the actual `libname` column.

Comment: @kl78 Yeah, you're right! Variable: libname, label: library name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `DQUOTE=ANSI` (default is `DQUOTE=SAS`) and then you'll be able to use quotation marks for names: `"library name"`.

You can find details here: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002473669.htm

Answer (score 0):

try to use `` mark...
or try to use the bracket []...
so it will be like `library name` or [library name];

```
select *
from sashelp.vtable 
where `library name` = xxx or [library name] = xxx;
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Both - ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, a quoted string,
              a numeric constant, a datetime constant, a missing value, (, +, -, BTRIM, CALCULATED,
              CASE, EXISTS, INPUT, NOT, PUT, SUBSTRING, TRANSLATE, USER, ^, ~.

Comment: This is MySQL specific.